# How to find out the rarkey value for delete key

Tags: livecode

How to find out the rarkey value for delete key. If I use rarkey then I can't use any other key is it any alternative method for "on rawkeyDown theKey"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you capture the rawKey value in a rawKeyDown handler, you must `pass` the message if you want any of the key presses to be handled by the engine. This is the case with any of the key messages you want to handle (e.g., rawKeyUp, keyDown, keyUp); if you do not `pass` the message, it's normal functionality will be preempted.

```
on rawKeyDown pCode
   if pCode is 65535 then
      # do what you want to do to handle the delete key here
   else
      pass rawKeyDown
   end if
end rawKeyDown
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to find out which raw codes are assigned to the various keys, do something like this (mind the formatting; comments don't allow code formatting): on rawKeyDown pCode; put pCode; pass rawKeyDown; end rawKeyDown